# How can I scroll a page for 5 minutes (or less if it finishes before) with puppeteer in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

How can I scroll page for 5 minutes (or less if the page finishes scrolling) using puppeteer in node js? I can only make the page scroll until it reaches the end of the page but I want to wait only 5 minutes or less if the scroll finishes before 5 minutes. The code I am using is below:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://twitter.com/Avengers');
    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1200,
        height: 800
    });

    await autoScroll(page);
})();

async function autoScroll(page){
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var totalHeight = 0;
            var distance = 100;
            var timer = setInterval(() => {
                var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
                window.scrollBy(0, distance);
                totalHeight += distance;

                if(totalHeight >= scrollHeight){

                    clearInterval(timer);
                    resolve();
                }
            }, 120);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the main function we'll define when to exit:

```
(async () => {
    // ...

    let finishTime = new Date().getTime() + (5 * 60 * 1000);

    await autoScroll(page, finishTime);

    // ...

})();
```

And will then pass that into `page.evaluate`:

```
async function autoScroll(page, finishTime){
    await page.evaluate(async (finishTime) => {

        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var totalHeight = 0;
            var distance = 100;
            var timer = setInterval(() => {
                var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
                window.scrollBy(0, distance);
                totalHeight += distance;

                if(totalHeight >= scrollHeight || new Date().getTime() > finishTime){

                    clearInterval(timer);
                    resolve();
                }

            }, 120);
        });
    }, finishTime);
}
```

Comment: Its very clear to me, thx :). The "finishes before part" is already in my code haha, I dont know why I asked for that again.